# Flask restful is doing GET instead of POST

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have a simple flask & flask_restful application built in python as shown:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class Route(Resource):
    def post(self):
        return "Posted"


api.add_resource(Route, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

However, when I run this app and navigate towards the link, I get this message:

```
{
    "message": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL."
}
```

And my flask output looks like this:

```
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 691-936-340
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Jun/2021 10:07:33] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

It appears my API is making a get call when it should be making a post. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you are navigating via browser it send `GET` request that's why you get 
`{"message": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL." }` 
i Tried send `POST` request Via Postman and it returned Valid Response.

Comment: Thank you. When I used curl in command line to access my URL that did return what I wanted.